# Secure Spring Cloud Gateway with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm new to both technologies, Spring Cloud and Keycloak.

I would like to have something like the architecture described in [the spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway), just working with Keycloak instead of Cloud Foundry UAA. 
I started with it but couldn't adapt it to Keycloak successfully.

In pom.xml file of the `security-gateway`, I updated Spring Cloud version to `Hoxton.SR1` and Spring Boot version to `2.2.4.RELEASE`. I also modified `application.yml` file to this:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  #  autoconfigure:
  #     TODO: remove when fixed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6314
  #    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          proxy:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: proxy
            client-secret: ce9db646-8fff-4652-83f3-8c77f48acb21
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-authentication-method: public
            redirect-uri: "http://localhost:8080/"
#            scope: openid,profile,email,resource.read,offline_access
        provider:
          keycloak:
#            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8190/uaa/oauth/authorize
#            token-uri: http://uaa:8090/uaa/oauth/token
#            user-info-uri: http://uaa:8090/uaa/userinfo
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrrealm
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
#            jwk-set-uri: http://uaa:8090/uaa/token_keys
```

When I run the main class and try to open `localhost:8080` by browser, I get this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Feb 02 00:54:35 IRST 2020
[409eabdf] There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
[not_allowed] Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client
```

And full stacktrace is this:

```
2020-02-02 00:54:35.736 ERROR 13228 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [409eabdf]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/?state=jBRwSTkrRXZLv3aOTWBqrfQ9bf9w_tUWtmr2RrsJirI%3D&session_state=7ef178c2-f2b4-4085-83da-0b94c8b139f6&code=66bcf3e8-98ce-4c37-8d50-bc9fb88cda45.7ef178c2-f2b4-4085-83da-0b94c8b139f6.c42cb75f-32f2-4049-8be4-5e5483fadd3d"

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [not_allowed] Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.oauth2AccessTokenResponse(OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Body from POST http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token [DefaultClientResponse]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/?state=jBRwSTkrRXZLv3aOTWBqrfQ9bf9w_tUWtmr2RrsJirI%3D&session_state=7ef178c2-f2b4-4085-83da-0b94c8b139f6&code=66bcf3e8-98ce-4c37-8d50-bc9fb88cda45.7ef178c2-f2b4-4085-83da-0b94c8b139f6.c42cb75f-32f2-4049-8be4-5e5483fadd3d" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.oauth2AccessTokenResponse(OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor$$Lambda$1047/190026310.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) [reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:419) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:209) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:367) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:363) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:412) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:572) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) [netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295) [netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

How should I fix the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the looks of it, the basic connection between keycloak and your app seems to work. What seems to be missing is the right role for the client, since the exception say that no offline-token is allowed. If you login to keycloak, change to `myrealm` and inspect the `clients`, you should be able to see which roles are mapped to the client. Make sure that the client has the role `offline_access`.

Comment: The client has this role.

Comment: From [the keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_offline-access): "*To be able to issue an offline token, users need to have the role mapping for the realm-level role offline_access. Clients also need to have that role in their scope. Finally, the client needs to have an offline_access client scope added as an Optional client scope to it, which is done by default.*" Can you check this aswell?

Comment: The user doesn't have this role. I added it and the problem solved apparently. But new problem raised! I get the HTTP 401 error. How should I configure the resource app to solve the new problem? I have also another question. Basically, why should I enable Offline Access feature?

Comment: HTTP 401 hints that the client is unathenticated. Is the client registered in the correct realm? Is the client activated? Is the client-secret correct? I would suggest to post the endpoint with a rest client, like insomnia or postman . Maybe [this article at baelung helps](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) --- Seems like spring-cloud fetches offline-tokens. I do not know why, but I am sure that this is configurable.

Comment: Something that just came to mind: have you added the redirect-url for the client and is the authorization code grant flow enabled? You could also try to access the tokens with the client admin-cli. If this should succeed, then the permission setup for your client is most likely incorrect.

Comment: First of all, I have to appreciate you, dear @Turing85, to spend your time to solve this problem. I'm sorry. client was public, not confidential. I correct it. Now, I can obtain access-token via curl. But I get 'Client secret not provided in request' in the browser, whereas I pass `client-secret` in application.yml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207061/discussion-between-turing85-and-vahidreza).

Comment: Finally, I solve the problem, thanks to [Tim te Beek](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/11/spring-cloud-gateway-with-openid-connect-and-token-relay/), by commenting out three lines in the application.yml: `authorization-grant-type`, `client-authentication-method` and `redirect-uri`.  Could anyone tell me what happened? :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/11/spring-cloud-gateway-with-openid-connect-and-token-relay/) and it's corresponding [github project](https://github.com/timtebeek/spring-security-samples/tree/master/spring-cloud-gateway-oidc-tokenrelay), problem solved by commenting out three more lines in application.yml: `authorization-grant-type`, `client-authentication-method` and `redirect-uri`.

Comment: Glad the blogpost helped! :)